# Christoffel Symbols for elliptic coordinate system

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, tensors

Does anyone know the Christoffel symbols of second kind for the elliptic coordinate system:

\begin{matrix}
x = R\cosh(u)\cos(v)\\ 
y = R\sinh(u)\sin(v)\\ 
z = z  
\end{matrix}

the metric tensor is given by:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
R^2(\sinh^2(u)+sin^2(v)) & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & R^2(\sinh^2(u)+sin^2(v)) & 0\\ 
 0&0  &1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

I calculated them but they differ from the ones published on Wolfram Mathematica website. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: What's the elliptic coordinate system?

Comment: if you update and give the metric I can calculate the symbols using GRQUICK.

Comment: @jman thank you! I just updated it.

Comment: Use $$\Gamma^i_{jk}=\frac{1}{2}g^{is}[g_{js,k}+g_{sk,j}-g_{jk,s}]$$

Answer (score 0):

This is what I obtained for the "u" element:

\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{\cosh (u) \sinh (u)}{\sin ^2(v)+\sinh ^2(u)} & \frac{\cos (v) \sin (v)}{\sin ^2(v)+\sinh ^2(u)} & 0 \\
 \frac{\cos (v) \sin (v)}{\sin ^2(v)+\sinh ^2(u)} & -\frac{\cosh (u) \sinh (u)}{\sin ^2(v)+\sinh ^2(u)} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}

using the package here: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/8329

I don't know if it conflicts with your site.

The "v" element

\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\frac{\cos (v) \sin (v)}{\sin ^2(v)+\sinh ^2(u)} & \frac{\cosh (u) \sinh (u)}{\sin ^2(v)+\sinh ^2(u)} & 0 \\
 \frac{\cosh (u) \sinh (u)}{\sin ^2(v)+\sinh ^2(u)} & \frac{\cos (v) \sin (v)}{\sin ^2(v)+\sinh ^2(u)} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Christofell symbols are supposed to be 3by3by3 arrays. I don't know what is that

Comment: It's the "u"th element.  Typically that means the matrix made by $\Gamma^{u}$

Comment: I see. would you mind uploading the "v" element as you call it? Apparently I was right and the Wolfram site is not. I tried to install the package but it doesn't work.

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez , sure give me a minute.  Although you should be careful with these symbols.  There is more than one convention to calculate these symbols and within those conventions there are sign conventions.

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez also what version of mathematica are you using?  I just used it on 11 and it worked fine.

Comment: I am using 11.2 Student Edition. Probably this educational edition has some restrictions.